# How to get Application path in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working in a spring mvc project which uploads an image and saves in the project folder which needs to be used in the project as .
The image file successfully comes to the controller but I'm unable to save the file in WebContent directory.

I would really appreciate help.
Regards Hari.

Item class

```
public class Item extends WebKinmelObject {
private String name;
private double price;
private String manufacturer;
private String description;
private String category;
private String imagePath;
private int quantity;
@Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date addedDate;

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}
public String getManufacturer() {
    return manufacturer;
}
public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
private MultipartFile file;
public MultipartFile getFile() {
    return file;
}
@Transient
public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}
public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}
public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public Date getAddedDate() {
    return addedDate;
}
public void setAddedDate(Date addedDate) {
    this.addedDate = addedDate;
}
```

}

My controller goes like this.

```
@RequestMapping("admin/addItemAction")
public ModelAndView addItemAction(@ModelAttribute("item")Item formItem,HttpServletRequest req){
    MultipartFile uploadedFile=formItem.getFile();
    if(uploadedFile!=null){
        String fileName=uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename();
        try {
            //-- if uploaded file is empty
            if(fileName!=""){
                //String imagePath="/Users/hari/Documents/workspace/WebKinmel/WebContent/resources/upload/"+fileName;
                String imagePath="/Users/hari/git/local_WebKinmel/WebKinmel/WebContent/resources/upload/"+fileName;
                File f=new File(imagePath);
                formItem.setImagePath("/WebKinmel"+imagePath.substring(imagePath.indexOf("/resources")));
                formItem.setFile(null);
                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);
                fos.write(uploadedFile.getBytes());
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                f.createNewFile();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("==>>The uploaded file cound not be saved");
        }
    }
    if(formItem.isPersisted()){

        // to be done if no image
        String fileName=uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename();
        if(fileName==""){
            Item i=(Item) WebKinmelServiceManager.find(formItem.getId(), Item.class);
            formItem.setImagePath(i.getImagePath());//transferring old image path if no image path found
        }
        Date date=new Date();
        formItem.setAddedDate(date);
        WebKinmelServiceManager.update(formItem);
    }
    else{
        Date date=new Date();
        formItem.setAddedDate(date);
        WebKinmelServiceManager.save(formItem);
    }
    System.out.println("object"+formItem+" saved");
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("admin/adminItem");
    addItemContent(mav);
    mav.addObject("recent", formItem);
    return mav; 

}
```

I want to save the image in WebContent directory rather than saving in 
'/Users/hari/git/local_WebKinmel/WebKinmel/WebContent/resources/upload/' directory

my servlet xml goes like this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.hari.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>

</bean>
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

<bean name="webkinmelProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
            <value>classpath*:webkinmel.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4):

As [Shailendra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1443084/shailendra) said, you can use ServletContext to get real path of your context. Easiest way to get ServletContext is autoware it in controller class. For example:

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public class ExampleController{

        @Autowired
        ServletContext context;

    }
```

After that you can use `context.getRealPath("/")` in controller's methods to get root path of your app context. But, again, as [Shailendra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1443084/shailendra) said, it will be better to use dedicated external folder instead of exploded war's folder.

I recommend you add property in you `webkinmel.properties` file with desired path:

```
webcontent.path=/Users/hari/git/local_WebKinmel/WebKinmel/
```

And use this property in you controller with spring injection:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerClass{

  @Value("${webcontent.path}")
  private String webcontentPath;

  ...
}
```

Or another way is pass property in config xml:

```
<bean name="myController" class="ControllerClass">
  <property name="webcontentPath" value="${webcontent.path}"/>
</bean>
```

To make folder accessible from browser, just add in you config xml:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/web/**" location="file:${webcontent.path}"/>
```

For example you saved file `hello.png` to `/Users/hari/git/local_WebKinmel/WebKinmel/`. It will be accessible by url `http://yourhost:8080/web/hello.png`

Comment: Thank you shailendra but since i am using eclipse for development, it is giving me the output path as.
"/Users/hari/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/WebKinmel/"

instead I need path something like 
"/Users/hari/git/local_WebKinmel/WebKinmel/"

any idea :) ??

Comment: Could you please something about webkinmel.properties file. I am not so much familiar with that .

Comment: According to your servlet.xml you have _webkinmel.properties_ in classpath of the project. This file should contain properties as _name=value_. You can add any properties in to this file, and get it in controller classes.

Comment: I was just trying to, haven't added the file. don't know how to implement it

Comment: Okay got some idea to add value to properties file.. but how to access via controller

Comment: thank you. this comment solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ServletContext#getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) to get the  path of the deployed/expanded WAR folder structure on the server file system.
Although saving an uploaded image inside the exploded war is **not recommended**. You should instead be using a dedicated external folder.

Comment: The package might not even be exploded.

Comment: @chrylis - yes you are right although most containers do create exploded structure but that cannot be depended upon, so it's always right to not add anything to the war content at runtime.

Comment: do you mean ==>ServletContext.getRealPath(), don't think ServletContext class has getRealPath() method, could you please elaborate :)

Comment: Please take a look at the doc in the link I have provided. I can see the method there.